# add custom code into a php file using my own plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Ive searched high and low for a nsippet that will help me do this but cant find anything.

I have created a custom plugin in wordpress and i would like a to ovveride and existing file with code written in the plugin? The code I want to replace is based in my woocommerce/template/emails folder in header.php

Any ideas how to get my plugin to do this so I can just write my custom code below it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't directly answer your question but to add custom code to woocommerce you can override your theme file with the following structure

> To override the admin order notification, copy:
>   wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to
>   wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php

Then in the overridden theme file you can add a hook which you can call from your plugin

**How to do the hook** 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/